# Regex not accounting for tab

Tags: php, regex

I'm having an issue getting my regex pattern to identify a tab. Here's my code:

```
$strings  = array(
    ' abc',
    '\tabc',
    '^abc'
);
$count = 0;
foreach($strings as $string){
    if (preg_match('/[\s\t\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string)){
        echo $string . "<br/>";
    }   
}
```

It only accounts for 2 items, `abc` and `^abc`, not `\tabc`

Comment: `'\tabc'` does not contain a tab, `"\tabc"` does.

Comment: Be aware that \s is a whitespace character and can include \t, depending on the language. It does in PHP.

Comment: Regarding to @Phil's answer, if you want to match `'\t'` then you can use `\\\\t`

Comment: @AndyG In the regex pattern, yes. `\s` matches whitespace characters including tab and newline

Comment: @Phil You could add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP to interpret control characters in strings (such as `\t`, `\r` and `\n`), you need to use double quotes, eg

```
$strings[] = "\tabc";
```